# In Django, how do you enforce a relationship across tables without using constraint?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm creating a simple list app that has Groups and Items, each with an associated User.  How can I enforce, in the model, that an item created by one user can never be linked to a group created by another user?  Here's the model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I've figured out this is impossible to do with a CheckConstraint in `class Meta` because constraints are apparently made in the database itself (I'm using postgres) and cross-table constraints are not allowed.

Coding without a framework, you would simply query the group before saving a link and throw an exception if the users didn't match.  So how do you do that in django?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out moments later.  From the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

You can override the save() method in class Item to do a check beforehand:

```
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
.
.
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if no user is given don't fail here; instead let normal integrity check catch it
        if hasattr(self, 'user') and self.user != self.group.user:
            raise IntegrityError("Item user must match group user")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I'll leave this open in case there's a better way...

Comment: Honestly, it seems like View logic, not something that should be constrained in the models.

Comment: Well this is a toy project, but the idea was to test isolating data between users.  If this was just handled by the view it would be very easy to make a mistake in some other view and expose one users data to another user.